# GetType does not exist a Reflection puzzle in VB

Tags: vb.net, reflection

This is a real basic schoolboy level error but I've not figured it out yet despite having used a fair amount of reflection in my generic updater class.

The puzzle is as follows: I want to get the type of a value that I've extracted in the code sample. Using that type I wish to compare it with another extracted value. To compare it correctly with Option Strict On I must directCast the extracted value to the type that the PropertyInfo says it is.

The code below simply illustrates my using it in Directcast or Ctype versions.

```
For Each p As PropertyInfo In _validProperties
           Dim NewValue = p.GetValue(UpdateItem)
           Dim x = CType(NewValue, p.PropertyType)  'Error p.PropertyType does not exist --How?
'Elided
Next 

'Alternative approach

For Each p As PropertyInfo In _validProperties
        Dim NewValue = p.GetValue(UpdateItem)
         Dim x = DirectCast(NewValue, p.PropertyType) 'Error p.PropertyType does not exist --How?
        'Elided
Next
```

I've tried explicitly putting the newly discovered type in it's own variable and it does exist.

This is an odd little trap I've had a few times and usually solved but this one is not budging. Therefore I'm fundementally misunderstanding how I need to use both the instance x.Gettype (OR GetType(Class) syntaxes).

Whatever I do, p.PropertyType does not exist.

Can anyone clear up my foggy mind on this please?

Edit: For now, Option Strict is off merely to allow this to work.

```
 For Each p In _validProperties
        Dim NewValue = p.GetValue(UpdateItem), OriginalValue = p.GetValue(originalItem)
        If (p.PropertyType.Name.Contains("Nullable") AndAlso Not Nullable.Equals(NewValue, OriginalValue)) _
            OrElse NewValue <> OriginalValue Then p.SetValue(originalItem, NewValue)
    Next
```

All my tests pass so I'll live with it for now. I simply don't want the update to fire if there is no difference between the values on the properties in question.

Comment: I can simply switch option strict off and the tests will pass in the main application. Just would prefer to keep it on :)

Comment: The compile error is a bit misleading, it has a hard time trying to figure out what you are trying to do.  Which is not possible.  The second argument of the TryCast or DirectCast operators must be an identifier that names a type.  It cannot be a variable.  So something like String or Integer or SomeClass can work.  p.PropertyInfo cannot work, the x variable can only ever be Object.  Such are the hazards of reflection, you are working with types that the compiler knows nothing about.  You'll have to rethink this.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I figured that because I capture the type from p.propertytype that explicitly returns a type, it'd be enough to make it work. The compiler disagrees.

Comment: ...because `CType/DirectCast/TryCast` require static types like `String`, `Control`, `Nullable`, etc. `p.PropertyType` is dynamic. As Hans already said you're required to keep it as `Object`. You'll have to cast afterwards instead by checking its type in an `If`-statement, like so: `If p.PropertyType Is GetType(Nullable) Then <cast to Nullable>`.

Comment: I've got the nullable part working previously thank you. My colleague is having a shot at finding a way to do this but based on what I've read, I would be amazed to see him succeed and it maintain good performance. Thanks for your help guys :).

Comment: Usually the check for equality is done in the property (like in CSLA). So you would call SetValues all the time but the Set of the property would only do specific logic of the Value is different. That way you know the type of the object. Here do UpdateItem and originalItem come from, are they parameters of the method? If yes, then your method could be a generic.

Comment: It is part of a generic updater class in fact.  CSLA?

Comment: Depending on implementation of the involved type's `Equals` method and conversion methods, perhaps you could use something like: `objOld.Equals(CTypeDynamic(objNew, objOld.GetType))`